# Seeking Concise Article on Motivations for and Benefits of Standards-Based Grading

Tags: primary-education, grading

I am preparing for my second year of implementing **standards-based grading** (SBG) in my 5th and 6th grade math course. I was thrilled with the benefits of using SBG with my students but found that I need to do more parent education. While I present a summary of SBG at my school's Parents' Weekend, not all parents attend or remember the details. I am, therefore, trying to develop a resource that I can link to in my email signature that will be accessible year-round.

I am looking for resources, **accessible to parents**, that summarizes why SBG is beneficial for students. The ideal source would be short (1-2 pages), outline the motivations for abandoning traditional grading processes, discuss the concept of growth mindset, and include details of how parents can support the SBG process.

I am happy to read through a big collection of articles, so please share anything you think might be pertinent.

---

Update: I have found some articles that are close to what I am looking for, but are not quite right. In general, most of the articles that I have found tend to spend too much time outlining a specific system for employing SBG or tend to be much too long. For example

1) [Miller - "A Better Grading System"](http://www.ncte.org/library/NCTEFiles/Resources/Journals/EJ/1031-sep2013/EJ1031Better.pdf) This article is too long for my needs and spends significant time describing a SBG system

2) [Marzano and Heflebower - "Grades That Show What Students Know"](https://www.ocps.net/lc/southwest/mso/parents/Documents/Grades%20That%20Show%20What%20Students%20Know.pdf) Similar issues to Miller's article above: too long and too much detailing of how a specific grading system would work.

---

Answer (score 8):

- From ACSD, Seven Reasons for Standards Based Grading -[Educational Leadership](http://www.ascd.org/publications/educational_leadership/oct08/vol66/num02/Seven_Reasons_for_Standards-Based_Grading.aspx)
  This article explains what SBG is and why it is beneficial.  It is written in a way that parents can relate to.

  Some of the points made:
- Grades and assessments become more meaningful for students, parents, and teachers.
- A chart is included showing how students might perform on different assignments and how SBG will make coherent sense of the variations.
- SBG is part of the larger picture of reform.

Comment: I +1'd your answer, the linked article is great. But, shouldn't answers here include a summary of the linked information? Or at least more than a link?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I am still new at this and appreciate the feedback.  Please let me know if my edits are what was needed.

Comment: Looks good to me. Just trying to help you avoid the 'link-only' answer. Especially for the fact that links break overtime.

Comment: Thanks Amy, that article is helpful! I am still interested in any others folks find too.

Comment: I just googled standards based grading and many interesting links came up.  You might want to try it.

Comment: I have done that and saw that your answer was the first link that came up. While that does provide a large number of resources, none seem to quite fit what I am looking for -- specifically geared towards parents to help them understand the purpose of implementing SBG. I will include some links to additional articles I have found as an answer.